# Mismatch in small-caps/caps in appendix sections numbering

Tags: sectioning, luatex, fontspec, titlesec, classicthesis

The MWE below creates a section numbering in the appendices of the form A.1, A.2 with A in small caps, but 1,2,3 in full caps. How can I either make A full caps or the number small caps?

```
\documentclass[twoside,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\PassOptionsToPackage{style=arsclassica}{classicthesis}
  \usepackage{classicthesis}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}

\begin{document}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix Test}
\section{Appendix Section Test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: changing font is not an option in this case. A solution for this would be great!

Answer (score 3):

You need a font that includes small cap numbers. Few do, even among commercial fonts. One free font that does is [EauDeGaramond](https://github.com/CatharsisFonts/EauDeGaramond):

```
\documentclass[twoside,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\PassOptionsToPackage{style=arsclassica}{classicthesis}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{EauTestText}
\begin{document}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix Test}
\section{Appendix Section Test}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

(I’m not recommending a Times/Garamond combination, just illustrating how a font with small cap numbers behaves.)

Comment: Nice example! Also, small caps letters generally blend well with lowercase numbers.

Comment: Is there a solution that does not involve changing fonts? It is not really an option in this case.

Comment: As Will Robertson commented, it will already be an improvement to use `\setsansfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Heros}`. I would hesitate to change things to full caps, because that would change the design and damage its unity.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Numbers=OldStyle`. But I warn you that the oldstyle digits in Heros are *ugly*.

```
\documentclass[twoside,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[style=arsclassica]{classicthesis}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Numbers=OldStyle]

\begin{document}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix Test}
\section{Appendix Section Test}

\textsf{1234567890}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the original, with Iwona and Palatino

[image]

You could use Iwona as well:

```
\documentclass[twoside,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[style=arsclassica]{classicthesis}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{Iwona}[Numbers=OldStyle]

\begin{document}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix Test}
\section{Appendix Section Test}

\textsf{1234567890}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, they are ugly. Is it possible to simply make the A full caps?